# Decoding in utf-8 in parsed data from website via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to parse data from website and I am getting an error.
Here's my python code

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = "http://ihned.cz"

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
#print(respData) #html kód

authors = re.findall(r'data-author="(.*?)"', str(respData))

for author in authors:
    print(authors)
```

And here's the error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 368: invalid continuation byte
```

Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of that website says `charset="windows-1250"`. Try `decode('windows-1250')`.